# Ionic App | Firebase Crashlytics does not work with Crash Reporting?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, plugins, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using @ionic-native/firebase plugin in our Ionic App, and crash reporting is included in this plugin. Since Firebase Crash Reporting will no longer be accessible after September 9, we are trying to switch to Firebase Crashlytics. But we're not getting any crash data on Crashlytics dashboard. Here's what I've tried:

- First, I followed [Get started with Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started), built and ran our App. 
  Then I found I could access Crashlytics dashboard, which I thought the SDK was implemented successfully. But after I crashed the app for a few times and waited for at least one day, but nothing showed up on either Crash Reporting or Crashlytics dashboard.
- Then, I reversed the changes made to our app and built & ran again, firebase console didn't change back. I found this plugin [cordova-plugin-firebase-crash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-crash) and installed it to my app successfully. 
  After crashing the app, almost immediately I got the crash data on Crash Reporting dashboard but no crashes on Crashlytics dashboard, but I could see the change on Crash-free statistics graph, which is weird. Now the Crashlytics dashboard looks like this:[Crashlytics dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjlhK.png)
  .

My question is: does crashlytics not work when crash reporting is used in the App? Or did I implement crashlytics wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firebase crash reporting is no longer available after Sep 8, 2018. I'm using cordova-plugin-firebase(V2.0.1) now and crashlytics works great.

Comment: I have the same issue as any cordova plugin is not provide separate plugin for crashlytics i though adding cordova-plugin-firebase will add crashlytics automatically unfortunately I am not able to see any crash report.. any help ??

Comment: I also installed the cordova-plugin-firebase but still not able to see any crash.. have u done anything extra ?

Comment: @KishanOza Great! I have put it as an answer too.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are stuck with cordova , try get capacitor (which also supports cordova out-of-box)

There’s a plugin for crashlytics

[image]

once you got the stuff set up you'll only have to

```js
import { Crashlytics } from 'capacitor-crashlytics';
const crashlytics = new Crashlytics();

//
// log user
crashlytics
  .logUser({
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "john@doe.com",
    id: "123"
  })
  .then(() => alert(`user logged`))
  .catch(err => alert(err.message));

//
// force a crash
crashlytics.crash();
```

Check this out to learn more

https://github.com/stewwan/capacitor-crashlytics

side note: I’m the creator, feel free to PR or file issues.

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own content. If you do so, you need to disclose that it's yours. If you don't disclose that it's your own content, it's often considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/165483) and [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Since Firebase Crash reports are working only with Native apps will this work anymore?

Comment: @Sampath have you got answer to your question? I am trying to configure Crashlytics for an Ionic app but I couldn't succeed. I think Crashlytics is for native apps.

Comment: Stewan do you have any recommendations for configuring Crashlytics for Ionic? Or the right question might be: Can we use Crashlytics in Ionic? Any alternative?

Comment: @lamostreta Yes, it works only with Native apps. i.e. no support for JS/web-based apps.

Comment: thanks for the info @Sampath. Have you find any crash reporting tool especially for Ionic mobile apps?

Comment: @lamostreta Yes, you can use Sentry/Capacitor here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/capacitor/

Comment: @Sampath you saved my life! thanks for this nice recommendation. I've been using Sentry in my Ionic App since 3 weeks and it helped me understand remote crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my mistake. 
I am using `cordova-plugin-firebase` and to check the crash I am using the `logEvent` and `logError` method of that plugin ttlo check whether it is reflecting to console or not but I for the first time I am not able to see any of the log.. I waited like 24 hours but then I read the documentation about the `Non-Fatal` error [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#log_non-fatal_exceptions) and check the `Firebase-plugin.java` and come to conclution that this 2 methods are basically logging the non-fatal error so you have to apply filter in firebase console to see you manual logs like this.. [image]

And when you app actually crashed by any reason you will defnalty see the logs in `Crashes` section..

Comment: can you please me to implemented this in crashlytics in ionic app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sentry Capacitor plugin here.

> Sentry's Capacitor SDK enables automatic reporting of errors,
> exceptions, and messages. It includes native crash support on iOS and
> Android.

**Official doc:** https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/capacitor/