# Integrate Firebase Crashlytics in my Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, crashlytics

So I wanted to integrate Firebase Crashlytics in my Ionic App. I followed the installation instructions [outlined here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-crashlytics#usage). However I am a bit confused at the usage section of the documentation.

The documentation mentions this piece of code:

```
import { FirebaseCrashlytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-crashlytics/ngx';


constructor(private firebaseCrashlytics: FirebaseCrashlytics) { }

...


const crashlytics = this.firebaseCrashlytics.initialize();
crashlytics.logException('my caught exception');
```

Where do I place this piece of code? Anywhere? Is the an example implementation available to look at? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. I don't think that you will get many valuable answers to you question since the question is very broad. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then tell us what you have tried so far - with code samples. Maybe in your case it would be best if you just google or search on youtube for firebase & ionic. There are tons of tutorials on this topic out there.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time asking a question here. Apologies. I have searched YouTube and searched YouTube but unable to find any solutions.

Comment: Please see if you find this helpful --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927827/ionic-app-firebase-crashlytics-does-not-work-with-crash-reporting

Comment: @wuzzy1237 have you implemented this crashlytics in ionic application..

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in "app.component" at start up:

```
constructor(...,  private platform: Platform, private firebaseCrashlytics: 
   FirebaseCrashlytics, ...) {
   super();
   this.initializeApp();
}


initializeApp() {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    ...
        this.firebaseCrashlytics.initialise();
    ...
   });
```

}

dont forget add to providers "FirebaseCrashlytics" in app.module.ts